# Prevent float from wrapping and force text-overflow when needed

Tags: html, css

I have three fields I would like on one line:

```
<div><span class="name">Blue Widgets Over Miami</span><span class="size"> large </span><span class="price">$9.99</span></div>
```

I'd like .name and .size to be on the left side of the line, .price on the right, and to always have at least a space between each field.

Here's the tricky part though. If the screen is really narrow, I don't want the div to wrap or overflow. Instead I'd like for .name to text-overflow as an ellipsis.

```
div{background:#abcdef;white-space:nowrap} 
.name{text-overflow:ellipsis} 
.size{} 
.price{float:right}
```

Right now if the screen is narrow then .price drops to a second line (which I don't want), and if the screen is even narrower then .name and .size overflow the div (which I also don't want), and .name never truncates with some ellipsis.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use flexbox:

```css
div {
  background: #abcdef;
  display: flex;
}
.name {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.size {
  margin: 0 .5em;
}
.price {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="name">Blue Widgets Over Miami</span>
  <span class="size">large</span>
  <span class="price">$9.99</span>
</div>
<br />
<div>
  <span class="name">Blue Widgets Over Miami Blue Widgets Over Miami Blue Widgets Over Miami Blue Widgets Over Miami Blue Widgets Over Miami Blue Widgets Over Miami Blue Widgets Over Miami Blue Widgets Over Miami Blue Widgets Over Miami Blue Widgets Over Miami</span>
  <span class="size">large</span>
  <span class="price">$9.99</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is awesome! I wasn't a fan of .size having margins so I ended up changing my line to: <div><span class="name">Blue Widgets Over Miami</span>&nbsp;large&nbsp;<span class="price">$9.99</span></div>. Besides that quirk of flex truncating my intended spaces, resolved by using the entity name of a space, this works great!

Comment: @GFL `&nbsp;` is not much semantic. If you don't want margins you can try `.size::before, .size::after { content: ' '; white-space: pre; }`

Comment: I noticed the flex box is causes text-alignment issues if the fonts aren't the same size. If I have .name larger than .size and .price, is it possible for all the text to share the same baseline?

Comment: @GFL `div { align-items: baseline }`

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are going for https://jsfiddle.net/kvb5hb6f/14/

I removed the floats and changed it to an absolute position to the right, then added `padding-right` to the parent div so that the text on the left will not over lap the price on the right, then added the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to the parent div.

```
div {
  background: #abcdef;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.price {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible to always have .size visible and only have .name overflow as ellipsis? Is it also possible to do this without specifying container widths as they are dynamic?